# PUT is blocking GET?

Tags: node.js, nock

I am trying to intercept a PUT request using nock, but something is going really strange...

My code has 2 calls, a GET request

```
http://internal-jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/CCC-2142
```

and a PUT request with payload

```
http://internal-jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/CCC-2142
     { fields: { reporter: { name: '8778469' } } }
```

The process is that it does the GET then uses info from there to do the PUT.

So I have also created 2 mock calls, one for the GET

```
nock('http://internal-jira.com.com', {allowUnmocked: true}).persist()

.get(/\/rest\/api\/2\/issue\/.*/)
.reply(400, (uri) => {
console.log(`!!!! Mocked GET: ${uri} !!!`);
})
```

and one for the PUT

```
 .put(/\/rest\/api\/2\/issue\/.*/)
 .reply(400, (uri) => {
 console.log(`!!!! Mocked PUT: ${uri} !!!`);
 })
```

If the GET code is active and I run my code then I can see that the code is being caught as I get the console.log()

```
!!!! Mocked GET: /rest/api/2/issue/CCC-2144 !!!
```

But if I comment out the GET and enable the PUT when I run my code, it fails and errors at the GET without it being mocked.

Its as if the PUT mock, is somehow intercepting the GET request (I guess as the URL is the same) but not actually doing anything with it, but also not letting the GET request through?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to use `.put` and not `.get` for the PUT operation. You example shows you using `.get` twice

Comment: Thanks, I have updated here in the write up, in the code it is the correct get/put..